# Bootstrap Switch, global checkbox to (un)check all other

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap Switch for Twitter Bootstrap. Here I have problem to check or uncheck all checkbox based on global checkbox checked or unchecked

Here is the bootstrap switch link http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/

Here is what I have done

```
<!-- this is the global checkbox -->
<div class="make-switch switch-mini">
    <input type="checkbox" id="rowSelectAll">
</div>

<!-- row checkboxs -->
<div class="make-switch switch-mini">
    <input type="checkbox" class="row-select">
</div>
<div class="make-switch switch-mini">
    <input type="checkbox" class="row-select">
</div>
<div class="make-switch switch-mini">
    <input type="checkbox" class="row-select">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#rowSelectAll").click(function () {
    $(".row-select").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

EDIT: tried with only one global and one local checkbox

```
<div class="make-switch switch-mini">
    <input type="checkbox" id="rowSelectAll">
</div>

<div id="toggle-state-switch" class="make-switch switch-mini row-select">
    <input type="checkbox" class="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one, it should work. Also see this jsfiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/URAcy/5/

```
  <!-- this is the global checkbox -->
<div class="make-switch switch-mini" id="rowSelectAll">
    <input type="checkbox" id="rowSelectAllc">
</div>

<!-- row checkboxs -->
<div class="make-switch switch-mini toggle-state-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="row-select">
</div>
<div class="make-switch switch-mini toggle-state-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="row-select">
</div>
<div class="make-switch switch-mini toggle-state-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="row-select">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#rowSelectAll').on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
    var $el = $(data.el)
      , value = data.value;
        $('.toggle-state-switch').each(function( index ) {
      $(this).bootstrapSwitch('setState' , value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil. thaks for your answer but it is not working properly. sometime it is selecting all and some time not. Uncheck event never works but only check even and that also sometimes

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 <!-- this is the global checkbox -->
<div class="make-switch switch-mini">
    <input type="checkbox" id="rowSelectAll">
</div>

<!-- row checkboxs -->
<div class="myswitch make-switch switch-mini">
    <input type="checkbox" class="row-select">
</div>
<div class="myswitch make-switch switch-mini">
    <input type="checkbox" class="row-select">
</div>
<div class="myswitch make-switch switch-mini">
    <input type="checkbox" class="row-select">
</div>
```

then in your script

```
    $('#rowSelectAll').on('change', function(){
    $('.myswitch').each(function(){

        if($(this).hasClass('switch-on')){
            $(this).bootstrapSwitch('setState' , false);
            $(this).removeClass('switch-on');
        }else{

       $(this).bootstrapSwitch('setState' , true);
        $(this).addClass('switch-on');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: nope, not working.. I found some event handler but don't know if how it works.. You may understand it better and can help to make it happen.. http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/#event-handler-javascript

Comment: @pixelngrain , that's what i am referring to you. Please see my update answer see if it will work

Comment: Id I should add on the global checkbox right? In that case it still didn't work.

Comment: @pixelngrain sorry I forgot updating it.. Please check it now again

Comment: I am sorry but this also doesn't work. I even tried using class but nothing happen

Comment: can you do me a favor, try making 1 checkbox only for your and see if you can toggle that using my script

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37719/discussion-between-drixson-osena-and-pixelngrain)

Comment: Thanks for the update and I have tried that too and still no change. Nothing happening. Please see my edited part what I have done.

Comment: @pixelngrain Check this one..http://jsfiddle.net/URAcy/4/. Also see my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

updated your fiddle - [ http://jsfiddle.net/URAcy/6/ ]

It should be

```
$('#rowSelectAll').on('switch-change', function(){....}
```