# HTML/PHP if-else Statement

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement

I am creating a website with Bootstrap and I would like to enter an if-else statement but I do not know how to do that. Let me explain:

Here is an image of my current HTML snippet:
[image]

Now what I want is, that if I change from "OFF" to "ON" by "An- / Ausschalten" that automatically the "Status aktuell" turns from "OFF" to "ON" and also the other way so it should look like this:

[image]

My current HTML code for this part is:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<div class="services-wrapper">
<h3>GENERALSTEUERUNG</h3>
Steuern Sie mit nur einem Klick die komplette Lichtanlage Ihres Hauses.<br><br>
<b>Status aktuell:</b> <input id="switch-offColor" type="checkbox" data-off-color="warning" data-size="mini" readonly><br><br>
<b>An- / Ausschalten:</b> <input id="switch-offColor" type="checkbox" data-off-color="warning" data-size="mini">        
</div>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me what if-else code I have to use to make this possible? What should the code look like so that this works?

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Better use javascript / jQuery for this.

Comment: There is no need of if else statement it can be done by jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi what you need to do is

first you track checkbox change event using

```
$('#ID').change(function() {
        // do any thing
    });
```

Then you have to set checked property of other checkbox

like

```
$("#id").attr("checked","checked");
```

your code should like similer to

```
$('#ID').change(function() {
var checked = $("#id").prop("checked");
            if (checked){
$("#id").attr("checked","checked");
}
        });
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

Comment: Why? I didn't create this question. I'm just saying that it's better to use `.prop`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate that. I am not really familiar with jQuery and it is really hard for me to understand your code. So compared to my HTML code at the beginning, how do I have to change the code so that it works?

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements with the same ID id ="switch-offColor". That is not good practice.
You should consider using class for this: class ="switch-offColor" if you want you css applied to the checkbox.

Then do this:

```
$(".switch-offColor").change(function(){
if($(this).prop('checked')){
    $(".switch-offColor").attr('checked','checked');
}
});
```

This will turn on the other checkbox too. If you want to turn it off again you apply similar code to handle the other status changes.

You can use another class to handle this and decouple your CSS:
class ="switch-offColor myLinked_checkboxes" or any name you choose.

Look at this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/73af3hjh/

Comment: Thanks for your code. At jsfiddle it is working, on my website it is not working. Please see here: http://smarthome.czellary.at/haushaltsgeraete.php (top left box)! When you look at the source code, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you're using bootstrap. That is different. Look at this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911067/bootstrap-switch-global-checkbox-to-uncheck-all-other