# A non-executing PHP if/else statement, with two choices for input submit button state

Tags: php, if-statement

The closest I could find to the physical description of my current dilemma is in the post [HTML/PHP if-else Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916016/html-php-if-else-statement) where the main issue similarity resides in the button state changes. As I'm not attempting anything in twitter-bootstrap, my issue is divergent from that point of reference. I'm dealing with overcoming (originally) terrible coding for a content publishing and retraction system.

This code;

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" />'; 
if ($row['is_published'] || $row['date_published']) {
    if($action == 'Retract') {
        echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Retract"/>';
    } else {
            if($action == 'Publish') {
                echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Publish"/>';
            }
     }   
 }      

 if($row['access_level'] > 1 || $_SESSION['access_level'] > 1){
     echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="$action" />';
 }
 echo'<input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete"/>';
```

returns the result of the submit inputs as being;

```
 _____________ ____________ ____________
|             |            |            |
|    EDIT     |  $ACTION   |   DELETE   |
|_____________|____________|____________|
```

I **KNOW** I'm doing something *simple* wrong because the state of the `$ACTION` input is supposed to change in relationship to whether the `$action` variable is influenced by database state change (embodied by `$row['is_published'] || $row['date_published']`). I've declared the `$action` variable previously

```
$action = '';
    if (isset($_GET['action'])) $action = $_GET['action'];
```

and I'm pretty sure my solution lies in the fact that I either mangled the nested `if/else` inside the original if statement or the echo of the `$action` input isn't helping to trip the (conditional) input state. I'm not having any problem whatsoever with the ability to publish/retract content - just getting the input to reflect the correct state depending on whether content is published (use 'Retract' input label value) or retracted (use 'Publish' input label value). I even toyed with the idea of using switch casing, but that was a bit of a train wreck - but no more so than the **ORIGINAL VERSION** I adapted;

```
if ($row[‘is_published’]) {
    $buttonType = “Retract”;
} else {
    $buttonType = “Publish”;
}
echo “<input type=’submit’ class=’submit’ “ .
    “name=’action’ value=’Edit’ /> “;
if (($row[‘access_lvl’] > 1) or ($_SESSION[‘access_lvl’] > 1)) {
    echo “<input type=’submit’ class=’submit’ “ .
          “name=’action’ value=’$buttonType’ /> “;
}
```

(**what a stinkin' mess, lol!**)

I'm disconsolately vexed that neither repeated perusal of Manual control structures nor consultation of original script control flow has provided a resolution of the matter. It could also be that I just don't see the forest for the trees. I'm afraid I've just read myself silly...but I'm pretty sure it's Human Error since I can never get the `$ACTION` input state to change according to content state.

**UPDATE**
Right now, I'm at the point where the database content state and the input label state are in unison sync (with database content in PUBLISHED state);

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" />'; 
if ($row['is_published'] || $row['date_published']) {

}                       
if($row['access_level'] > 1 || $_SESSION['access_level'] > 1){
if ($action=='Retract') {
      echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Publish"/>';
             } else {                
      echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Retract"/>';

     }         
    }
  }
echo'<input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete"/>';
  }
```

The above code;

### result return

```
 _____________ ____________ ____________
|             |            |            |
|    EDIT     |  RETRACT   |   DELETE   |
|_____________|____________|____________|
```

EXACTLY what I want to see. BUT, rather unfortunately, the input label state remains the same when clicked even though the database content state indeed changes - in this case - allowing for the retraction of the content. I'm so close I can taste it.

What's really stomping my brain is the fact that I have to manually alter the `$action` variable and the echo statement values to have the input/content states to correctly unison sync - **which is the whole point of the if/else statement in the first place (lol!)**.

I mean, I even went off on a little troll on comparison operators as I was
trying to evoke an inadvertant error somewhere which would lead to a resolution, but whether =, ==, or === was employed, it didn't seem to influence the proceedings (I thought for sure = would shake something loose). I understand that `else` is used for an alternate block of coding ***if the 
IF CONDITION is false***. Trying to abstain from "code-flail" at this point, but more reading seems necessary.

Thanks to all for the eyes/views as well as **@Darren** and **@take** for their splendid insights. I'll smash this flat yet...

**2ND UPDATE**

Having had a *"whoops"* moment;

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" />';  
if (empty($action) == 'Retract') {
      echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Publish"/>';
             } else { 
        if ($row['is_published'] || $row['date_published']) {
        if(empty($action) == 'Retract') {   
      echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Publish"/>';
    }
   }                
 }
 echo'<input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete"/>';  
}}}
```

**Just because I'm harried, no need for sloppiness (code refactor granting exact same result).**

**3RD UPDATE**

```
echo '
<br>
<div class="searh_form">
<form method="POST" action="transact_blog.php">
<div>
 <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit"/>
 <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete"/>';

if($row['access_level'] > 1 || $_SESSION['access_level'] > 1){
if(!empty($row['date_published']) and !empty($row['is_published'])){
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Publish"/>';
} else {
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Retract"/>';
          }
       }
   }
}
```

In between apoplectic fits of laughter and Derp-level code rages, I'm at the point of mental/physical exhaustion. Thanks to suggestion about `form` submission by both @Sharky and @Darren, the `$action` variable was given the `$_POST` initialization. Sadly, I find that a potential key may be that I have to allow all the inputs to exist and then do some sort of `is_array` explosion to create a strictly-enforced conditional functionality.

For me, the issue exists about how to flip the input **label** state to match whether or not the database content was published or unpublished. It really just cannot be that hard. I'm almost at the point where I'm considering some JS or jQuery that I could wrap in, but I just don't want to go that route unless absolutely necessary (I **do** have "utility lines" that I use echoed out in PHP - mostly for repetitive tasks, but I'm reluctant to make large user-functionality leveraged on JS). Manually-altering this section;

```
if(!empty($row['date_published']) and !empty($row['is_published'])){
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Publish"/>';
} else {
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Retract"/>';
}
```

by stripping the `!empty()` and swapping the `$action` variable values, I achieve the ability to make input label and database content publishing states to run the (desired) code execution.  This aspect is what keeps me laughing rather than crying (lol!)...**more reading...**

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

I had decided to delete the line

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="'.$_POST['action'].'" />';
```

as it wasn't crucial to the functionality of the publishing/retraction since the process still executed as designed and implemented. For me, the splinter was (is still) that I wasn't able to figure out how to make the `$action` variable grab onto either the `'Retract'` / `'Publish'` values. **...more reading.**

**LAST UPDATE**

About to lose it...eleven days since I've been completely stopped in my tracks. I have read until I've passed out, code-flailed repeatedly, had a number of functions I thought I'd nailed down become problems again (to be nailed flat again), and round and round in what's fast becoming my personal Ninth Circle of Coding Hell;

```
if($row['access_level'] > 1 || $_SESSION['access_level'] > 1){ 
  if(empty($row['is_published']) || $action != 'Retract'){
            echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Publish"/>';
  }
  elseif($row['is_published'] || $action != 'Publish'){
        echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Retract"/>';
  } 
}
```

The `$action` variable (which I `POST`ed per suggestions from @Darren and @Sharky) was `isset` earlier in the code;

```
$action = false;
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
   $action = $_POST['action'];
} 
echo $action;
```

At this point, I'm in an advanced state of hermitage over this and fast approaching mental disrepair. The only positive element in this whole sordid mess is the fact that I find myself exhuming humor from the dour fact that ***MANUALLY*** swapping the places of the two echoes in the former code chunk is what changes the input label state to respond to the database content status (published or retracted) and not the if...else if statement. I just can't believe that there hasn't been even a crumb of a pointer under any of the rocks I've overturned lately. Just a whole lot of bad advice and deprecated solutions (that won't even work, lol!). If I could just find a way to force the echoes to swap places, I'd be golden. :longsigh: Now, it's by any means necessary...

**LAST-DITCH (MERCY-KILLING NECESSARY/REQUESTED)**

I just don't know what else to do...seems I've exhausted all possibilities getting the input label states to "flip" from "Retract" <=> "Publish". I'm at this point doubting that this may be a pure PHP solution. Actually got in touch with the publishers where this (horrible) code concept originated, and was fluffed off with a, "We\'ll get this info to the respondible parties (lol!)". At this point, I'm just begging for any hint of a crumb on how to go about this.

I've isolated it down to (what I'm thinking is) the `ELSE` part of the `if/else` is the culprit, but I don't know how to go about force-effecting it like I successfully did in the `if` part;

```
CODE:
-----
echo '<br><div class="searh_form"><form method="post" action="transact_article.php"><div>';

echo '<p><br>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit"/>';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$submitted_array = array_keys($_POST, [0], $action);
echo ($_POST['action'][$submitted_array[0]] . " " . $submitted_array[0]);
}
if (empty($row['is_published']) || !$row['is_published'] && empty($row['date_published']) || !$row['date_published'] && $action != $_POST['action']  || $action != '') {
$action = "Publish";
}else{
if (!empty($row['is_published']) || $row['is_published'] && $row['date_published'] || $row['date_published'] && $action == $_POST['action']  || $action != $_GET['action']) {
$action = "Retract";
}}
if (($row['access_level'] > 1) || ($_SESSION['access_level'] > 1)) {
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="'.$action.'" />';
}

echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" />';
}}
?>
<input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/>
</p>
</form>

  RESULT:  
  -------
   _____________ ____________ ____________
  |             |            |            |
  |    EDIT     |  PUBLISH   |   DELETE   |
  |_____________|____________|____________|
```

Re-employment of the line
`echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="$action" />';`
allowed me to achieve above result - which is just how I need to have all the pending content appear before editing/posting. Please, I'm humbly inquiring after just what it is I can do to get my label to flip to "Retract" when there has been approved updating of the database content state. Thanks for **ANY** additional pointers I can get. I'm about at the end of my rope on this...

**What in the Name of Sanity is it going to take?!?!?**
Declaration of two-element array:

`$buttonType = array('Publish', 'Retract');`

The solution began to surface once I got onto the fact that the `if/else` was referring to an array structure - the `print_r()` being

`Array ( [0] => Publish [1] => Retract )`

GREAT! But, unfortunately I wasn't able to tap the numeric indices within the `if/else` to force the `$buttonType` variable to display the **Retract** value as I got a fatal error as `[]` isn't allowed for reading in PHP

```
$buttonType = array('Publish', 'Retract');
if (isset($_POST['buttonType']) && $buttonType == $_POST['buttonType']) {
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
return $value;    
}
}
if ($row['is_published'] && $row['date_published'] && $buttonType != 'Publish') {
$buttonType = "Retract";
} else {
if (empty($row['is_published']) && empty($row['date_published']) && $buttonType != 'Retract') {
$buttonType = "Publish";
}
}
if (($row['access_level'] > 1) || ($_SESSION['access_level'] > 1)) {
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="'.$buttonType.'" />';
}
```

This current rewrite produces the desired result for 'Unpublished';

```
 _____________ ____________ ____________
|             |            |            |
|    EDIT     |  PUBLISH   |   DELETE   |
|_____________|____________|____________|
```

However, after submitting the form, even though I get the content to become 'Published', the input value still remains unchanged. There has to be a simpler way to flip input value states. I'm still bogged down trying to see how I can access the numeric indices.

Comment: This is by far the best use of english language i've seen in stackoverflow. Very good sir!

Comment: Thank you, KINDLY, @Sharky - I'm trying to operate on the premise of providing relevant, ACCURATE information to show that I've done some work to try and sort my own coding issues. Thank you again.

Comment: i'm shooting kinda blind but i'll give it a try: 1) Make sure the values of `$action` have a standard through your code. I see first letter is capital, remember 'Retract' is not the same as 'retract'. make sure the `$_GET` values comply with your capitalization through your code. 2) Are you sure the `action` variable is always coming through `$_GET`? because i see you are using it in `input`s, which i assume, they are in a `form`, which i believe will `$_POST` these values. That means in the second "toggling" of states, the `$action` will be in `$_POST['action']` and not in `$_GET['action']`

Comment: <continue from previous comment> so your initialization will fail. In this case you should check something like `if (isset($_GET['action'])) {$action = $_GET['action'];} elseif (isset($_POST['action'])) {$action = $_POST['action'];}` let me know if my guess was correct! :D

Comment: Thanks for that tip, @Sharky - I actually had tried it both ways separately (in succession), but I wasn't aware you could duck and cover like that (lol!), and it's a nice little tip I'm tucking away for future usage. Unfortunately, I'm still battering ram on it. Am checking your suggestion of the second toggling of states. Going to be a long night...

Comment: Just found out that the code I'm working with is (almost) straight out of a Wrox.com manual entitled **Beginning PHP 6, Apache, MySQL 6 Web Development** - had no idea (lol!). Just shot them an email on the nature of my issue with a link to this SO posting. Will share the resolution that their tips bring when it becomes available.

Comment: Sometimes it pays to go with the debug - `var_dump($_SERVER);` tells me for sure that **`["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "GET"`**. Now it's a brand new ballgame (lol!).

Comment: This is definitely a case of not seeing the forest for the trees...if I had thought to investigate along the lines of arrays with numeric indices, I'd probably have been done about ten days ago (lol!). **NOW** my focal point becomes how do I get the array values (which I've already tested for, bringing back the original variable, $buttonType, since I didn't want to have a collision with the input name attribute and was part of the problem keeping me from seeing I needed to use an array in the first place) into the if/else statement. **At this point, not feeling so crabby (lol!)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terrible code is hard to overcome at times. My mistake was to try and follow pointless logic initially. Once the idea hit me to focus on the array business as the key to the input state flip that I was desperate for earlier;

```
echo '<br><div class="searh_form"><form method="post" action="transact_article.php"><div><p><br>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" />';
foreach ($buttonType as $key=>$value){
  if ($row['is_published'] && array_key_exists([0], $buttonType, TRUE)) {
  if (($row['access_level'] > 1) or ($_SESSION['access_level'] > 1)) {
 $buttonType[] = '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Retract"/>';
   } else {
 $buttonType[] = '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Publish"/>';
 }}
 echo "<input type='submit' name='action' value=\"$buttonType[$key]\" />";
 }
 echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" />';
 }}
?>  
<input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/>
</p>
</div>
</form>
<br>
```

I had to do some physical repositioning of some of the code - moving the `if/else` within the `foreach` statement, tuning up the connection of `$buttonType` variable to the target inputs (having declared the `$buttonType` array further up in the page), while still not altering how the inputs were expected to act to fulfill the functions of publishing/retraction.

**WORKS EXACTLY AS REQUIRED...another flawless victory...**

Answer (score 0):

If you've narrowed down you possible actions to those 2, you could simply run a `switch/case`:

```
switch($action) {
    case "Retract":
    echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Retract"/>';
    break;
    case "Publish":
    echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="Publish"/>';
    break;

}
```

**Your Issue:** is that you're passing a string, instead of concatenating the variable. What you want to do is echo your input like this:

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="' . $action . '" />';
```

A more effective method of printing out your inputs is this:

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='action' value='{$action}' />";
```

Your issue was because you were passing the `$action` as a string, not having it evaluated. If you want to evaluate it in the string like that, you'll need to use `"` instead of `'`.

Comment: I'm on nuclear face palm at the second as I can't believe I missed such a rudimentary by not concatenating the $action variable. Your switch was way more successful that what I tried earlier, but I'm still having the issue of the input not being able to grab either choice automatically as a result of the state change of the database content. @Darren, thank you for that issue spot. Going back to Manual-land now. **I'm missing something completely simple...** Thanks again.

Comment: @HomeOffice Can you show your form HTML? Is it `method="get"` or `method="post"`?

Comment: it's `POST` method - and, a little weird since the `form` consists of the if/else input choices of the `$action` variable, edit input, and delete input not the standard `form` - just trying to figure out why the `$action` variable is being recalcitrant to state change.

Comment: @HomeOffice that would be because you're trying to set the `$action` with `$_GET['action']` instead of with `$_POST['action']`. Change it to this: `f (isset($_POST['action'])) $action = $_POST['action'];  `

Comment: followed your suggestion and change - still not getting what I need in the button flipping from PUBLISH <=>RETRACT. Thank you for all your help and suggestions, but I'm calling it a night since I didn't sleep last one (lol!).

Comment: you should definitely seperate the business logic from the view.

Answer (score -1):

Your `$action` isn't recognized as variable because of the `'` symbol.

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="action" value="' . $action . '" />';
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response @take - but I'm still not getting the desired result. I appreciate the pointer to the single-quoting error I was making in the echo. DEFINITELY my Human Error.